# ¿Cerrar un modal usando JQuery y Materialize?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal, materialize

Hago de nuevo la pregunta porque con todas las respuestas que me dieron todavía no pude solucionar el problema, lo cual además me parece super extraño porque varias de las respuestas tienen mucha lógica!

**¿Que necesito?**

Abrir un modal al hacer click en una imagen y que luego el modal se cierre solo al hacer click fuera de la misma.

**¿Que uso?**

Materialize y JQuery y Thymeleaf (pero no debería afectar en nada)

---

**Código HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>

    <link rel="icon" th:href="@{/favicon_heladeria.png}" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/vendor/materialize/css/materialize.css}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/app.css}" />

        <h2 class="mid-title">Nuestros Helados</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="helados container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 l4" id="chocoDiv">
                <a class="modal-trigger" href="#chocolateModal">
                <img class="tastes" th:src="@{/images/chocolate.png}" />
                </a>
                <span class="taste-name">CHOCOLATES</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12 l4">
                <img class="tastes" th:src="@{/images/crema.png}" />
                <a href="#"></a>
                <span class="taste-name">CREMAS</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12 l4">
                <img class="tastes" th:src="@{/images/dulceDeLeche.png}" />
                <a href="#"></a>
                <span class="taste-name">DULCE DE LECHES</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12 l4">
                <img class="tastes" th:src="@{/images/frutales.png}" />
                <a href="#"></a>
                <span class="taste-name">FRUTALES</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="chocolateModal" class="modal">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Chocolates</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script th:src="@{/vendor/jquery/jquery-1.11.3.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/vendor/materialize/js/materialize.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/app.js}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Dejo los comentarios para que vean las otras opciones que probé sin lograr nada útil :(

**Código JS:**

```
$(function(){
    // Activate mobile nav
    $(".button-collapse").sideNav({edge: 'right'});
});

//  $(document).ready( () =>{
//    $('.modal').modal();
//  });

// ESTE FUE EL ÚNICO QUE ANDUVO (Pero luego no lo puedo cerrar)

//$('#chocoDiv').on('click', () => {
//    $('#chocolateModal').show();
//});

document.querySelector('#chocoDiv').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var element = document.querySelector('#chocolateModal');
    var modal = M.Modal.init(element, {});
    modal.open();
});

//$(document).ready(function(){
//    $('.modal').modal();
//  });
```

¿ Alguna idea de que puedo estar haciendo mal ? Es raro que ninguna opción ande bien !

Comment: Estas usando el modal de bootstrap ?.. o Jquery ?

Comment: Solo JQuery ... y una librería que se llama Materialize

Comment: necesitas que cuando den click fuera de la modal se cierre, no?

Comment: Si, eso mismo, nada más!

Comment: Veamos compañero... Por empezar inmediatamente despues de `<h2 class="mid-title">Nuestros Helados</h2>` veo que cierras un `</div>` que no veo que lo estes abriendo anteriormente. De todos modos ese dudo que sea el error, pero te lo informo de todos modos. Ahora lo vemos y edito la respuesta.

Comment: Bueno, logré solucionarlo! Parece que el tema era la versión de Materialize que estaba usando ... no me reconocía el M del modal ... parece que hay que usar esta versión para que te lo reconozca:  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No necesitas `#modalOut` los modales de materialize tienen una opción que es `dismissible`. Esta opción lo que hace es que al hacer click fuera del modal se cierre. Su valor por defecto es **True**. Puedes ver la documentación [Aquí](https://materializecss.com/modals.html). 
Te recomiendo trabajar con instancias del plugin. En ese doc también te enseña como hacerlo. Te da mayor facilidad para trabajar con eventos en un futuro.

Te dejo un ejemplo que espero que sea lo que estabas necesitando. Saludos!

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
  });
```

```css
img{
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Modal Trigger -->
  <a class="modal-trigger"    href="#modal1">
  <img src ="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/es/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=62634cce9d6c" />
  </a>

  <!-- Modal Structure -->
  <div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4>Modal Header</h4>
      <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <a href="#!" class="modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**Edición con opción 2 usando el código del usuario que pregunta:**

**Es muy importante esto. Creo que en parte tu error esta en no inicializar .modal**

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
  });
```

```css
img{

width:200px;
height:200px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


 
        <h2 class="mid-title center">Nuestros Helados</h2>
    
    <div class="helados container">
        <div class="row center">
            <div class="col s12 l4" id="chocoDiv">
                <a class="modal-trigger" href="#chocolateModal">
                <img class="tastes" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/es/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=62634cce9d6c}" />
                </a>
                <p class="taste-name">CHOCOLATES</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12 l4">
            <a class="modal-trigger" href="#CREMASModal">
                <img class="tastes" th:src="@{/images/crema.png}" />
             </a>
                <p class="taste-name">CREMAS</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12 l4">
            <a class="modal-trigger" href="#DULCEModal">
                <img class="tastes" th:src="@{/images/dulceDeLeche.png}" />
               </a>
                <p class="taste-name">DULCE DE LECHES</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col s12 l4">
            <a class="modal-trigger" href="#FRUTALESModal">
                <img class="tastes" th:src="@{/images/frutales.png}" />
               </a>
                <p class="taste-name">FRUTALES</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Modal Chocolate -->
    <div id="chocolateModal" class="modal">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Chocolates</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

 <!-- Modal CREMAS -->
    <div id="CREMASModal" class="modal">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4 class="modal-title">CREMAS</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
     <!-- Modal DULCE -->
    <div id="DULCEModal" class="modal">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4 class="modal-title">DULCE DE LECHES</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <!-- Modal FRUTALES -->
    <div id="FRUTALESModal" class="modal">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4 class="modal-title">FRUTALES</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: No uso BootStrap, solo JQuery

Comment: Estoy siguiendo esta docu, de hecho mi publicación la hice después de leerla bien ... voy a seguir intentando, gracias. Cuando me salga las acepto las respuestas

Comment: Dale, mira yo hice un proyecto con  materialize y si no trabajas con instancias después se vuelve un dolor de cabeza para cosas mas complejas. Que es lo que no estas logrando hacer?

Comment: La verdad ya es un dolor de cabeza hacer un solo modal :/
Lo que quiero hacer es crear un modal al hacer click en una imagen. Luego hacer click fuera de la imagen y que el modal se cierre, algo bien facil para luego seguir con algo más complicado. Pero no me sale! Siguiendo la docu y todo :/

Comment: es MUY mala la documentación !

Comment: @Nacho Zve De La Torre Es cuestión de agarrarle la mano. Después esta muy bueno materialize :) Fijate ya edite la respuesta haciéndolo con una imagen.

Comment: fijate que edité la publicación con el ćodigo que tengo para que veas que sigue sin andar ... seguí código de ejemplo, de echo tiene mucha lógica y es como se usa en la documentación, pero sigue sin andar ... que estaré haciendo mal ??

Comment: @Nacho Zve De La Torre Ahora tienes un ejemplo con tu codigo. Es muy importante inicializar .modal. Aparte la corrección de tu etiqueta de cierre div antes del titutlo. Saludos!

Comment: ! Muchas gracias por tu enseñanza y ayuda hermano. Te mando un abrazo grande :)

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con este.

```
$('#modalOut').on('click', () => {
    $('#chocolateModal').closeModal();
});
```

Comment: Tampoco me anda :(  Pensé que iba a ser más facil jaja

Comment: prueba con este $('#modalOut').on('click', () => { $('#chocolateModal').closeModal(); });

Comment: las respuestas que son solo código y no tienen nada de explicación son consideradas de baja calidad, mira [answer] y mejora tu respuesta por favor

Comment: Hola Juan. En vez de poner "prueba esto" explica el funcionamiento del codigo para que la respuesta sea de más calidad. Y en vez de comentar alternativas, pulsa en [edit] para cambiar la respuesta segun el codigo más actualizado. mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Solo tienes que especificar que este id es un modal.

```
$('#modalOut').on('click', () => {
   $('#chocolateModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Sigue sin andar che, alguna otra opción, o estoy haciendo algo mal yo ?

Comment: ah me confundi en algo, ya te lo edito. me avisas si te funciona. estas usando esos modales de bootstrap?

Comment: noup, no uso bootstrap ... solo Jquery y una libreria que se llama Materialize

Comment: Podrias revisar la documentacion de materialize https://materializecss.com/modals.html prueba con $('#modalname').closeModal(); or  $('#modalname').modal('close'); y ademas agregar la etiqueta Materialize a la pregunta, porque por defecto se asume la respuesta de bootstrap (que son las mencionadas mas arriba)

Answer (score 0):

Segun la documentacion para abrir una ventana modal de Materialize es:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal').modal();
  });
```

este seria el codigo usando Jquery, donde hacer referencia para abrir la modal por la clase.
Tambien tienes la version completa:

```
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            var Modalelem = document.querySelector('.modal');
            var instance = M.Modal.init(Modalelem);
            instance.open();
        });
```

Para cerrar seria:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.modal').modal('close');
    });
```

espero te sirva.

Te sugiero revisar la documentacion !!

[Documentacion-Modal](https://materializecss.com/modals.html)

Answer (score 0):

Quizás esto te funcione: en este ejemplo la palabra **Hola** abre el modal mediante **"Om.onclick"**, **Om** siendo el Id de P.

```js
var modal = document.getElementById('chocolateModal');

Om.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
}
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<p id="Om">Hola</p>
<div id="modalOut">
<div id="chocolateModal" class="modal">
        <div>
            <div class="modal-content">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Chocolates</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciona con esto:

```
<div class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        Contenido modal
    </div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn">Modal</button>

<script>
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  var element = document.querySelector('.modal');
    var modal = M.Modal.init(element, {});
    modal.open();
  });
</script>
```

Al hacer click sobre el botón creas una instancia del modal y le pasas como parámetro el elemento html con clase `.modal` y las opciones. Luego, llamásal método `open()` y debería funcionar.

Como dijeron, por default el modal es dismissible, lo que significa que se cerrará al hacer click afuera o con la tecla <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Según tu planteamiento seria así:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.modal').modal();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<div class="helados container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 l4" id="chocoDiv">
      <a class="modal-trigger" href="#chocolateModal">
      <img class="tastes" src="https://cdn-3.expansion.mx/dims4/default/ac14b43/2147483647/strip/true/crop/4830x3206+0+0/resize/800x531!/quality/90/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcherry-brightspot.s3.amazonaws.com%2Fce%2F69%2F17d61fd24182bd3dda71306e54ff%2Fshutterstock-524456035.jpg" width="200"/>
       
       <span class="taste-name">CHOCOLATES</span>
      </a>
    </div>            
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="chocolateModal" class="modal">
  <div>
    <div class="modal-content">
      <h4 class="modal-title">Chocolates</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Con esto abres la modal danle click a la imagen y se cierra cuando le das click fuera de la misma. Espero te sirva